# CheckBox is not printed by Adobe Reader DC - iText 7.1.0 for Java

Tags: itext7

I've got some really big problems with AcroForm CheckBox.
1. CheckBox (in checked state) is not printed by Adobe Reader DC. Even after setting the corresponding FieldFlag. Maybe this is because I have'nt got the font ZapfDingsbats on my Computer?
[image: Adobe Reader Preview]
2. How do I change this font (I want to use Wingdings) for all the symbols (On/Off state) used by the different appearances of the checkbox?
3. Last but not least: How to draw a border around the unchecked CheckBox?
Thanks a lot for every tip and help!

```
package jumpstart;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfButtonFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Problem6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("problem6.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        PdfButtonFormField checkBox = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(pdf, new Rectangle(75, 750, 20, 20), "cbName1", "On",
                PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS);
        // checkBox.setFieldFlag(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        form.addField(checkBox, page);
        pdf.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("problem6.pdf"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, you should actually post one question at a time instead of grouping them all together.

Comment: I didn't realize you had supplied the code to produce the document. This is definitely the case. Add this line to have the checkbox's normal appearance stream appear during printing: checkbox.getPdfObject().put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(4));

Comment: Alexey's suggestion of `checkBox.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);` is better- it does the same thing under the hood without the magic number and makes it clear what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**. To make the `PdfFormField` printable you should use the following method:

```
checkBox.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
```

**Part 2**. In your particular case the appearance of the checkbox is drawn using canvas instructions, not any fonts. This is how it's done:

```
q
Q
0 20 m
20 0 l
20 20 m
0 0 l
S
```

**Part 3**. As you can see, no fonts are used, the cross is drawn with lines.
Thus, it's not possible easily to use different font. You can create your own appearance stream and set it via `PdfFormField#setAppearance`. But you have to be very careful and know what you are doing.

You can set field border with these lines:

```
checkBox.setBorderWidth(1);
checkBox.setBorderColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
```

But this would set borders for all the appearances, including `On` and `Off`. If you want the border to be drawn only for `Off` appearance, you should create your custom appearance and use `PdfFormField#setAppearance`.

**P.S**. Please ask questions separately. The three questions you asked are different ones.

Comment: Thank you for the information! You are right, next time I will ask a single question von each problem.

Comment: Part 1: That's what I was looking for. It works fine!. Part 2: Now I understand that the symbols are drawn and are not coming from a font. Part 3: Thanks for the tip, I will give appearance a try. The statements setBorderWidth and setBorderColor don't seem to work for checkbox!

Comment: @DirkKampfmeier where do you place the border settings? You should place them before `form.addField(checkBox, page);`. I've tried them just with your code and it works for me.

Comment: After leaving the field (click on the white page) there is no border. When rollover or clicking there is a border with these 2 statements. BorderWidth only works for rollover!